# My Canon EOS 500 Film Camera has all of a sudden stopped working

Tags: canon, battery

My   Canon EOS 500 camera used to be my dad's for many years before he gave it to me. I've been using it for a couple of months now and it has been working fine.

Last week I went to use it again but when I turned it on, nothing happened, the display wasn't showing anything either. I assumed the batteries had died so I purchased new ones, Duracell DL123A 3V Lithium Batteries to be exact. After putting in the new batteries still nothing was working, including the display.

Does anyone know what the problem could be and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have a way of testing the voltage output of the new batteries?

Comment: battery compartment contacts corroded, batteries in backwards, battery door not closing properly,

Answer (score 1):

I can understand the camera has a history that gives it sentimental value. As a tool for making pictures, it can be replaced with a working version for relatively little money. Another similar or “more advanced” camera is also an option.

I’m sure it is disappointing, but if the goal is making pictures then it has done that. To pursue picture making the simplest path is replacement with something that works.

The memories of your family will still be there if it sits on a shelf. And a degree of cold-bloodedness toward gear is part of evolution as a photographer. Equipment breaks if you use it. And it often breaks if you don’t. So just use it and remember the important point is picture making not gear ownership.

Comment: At the time of this answer, there’s a working copy on US eBay with free shipping for less than $30.

Comment: Adding to your answer, perhaps the camera could be retired to a "place of honor" as a decoration on a shelf, making it a personal _objet d'art_. Keeps the sentimental value, but its working days are retired.